# How do I specify shared attributes translations between models in I18n locale file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization, locale, models

I tried the following:

```
es:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      name: Nombre
```

And it did not work.

But the following do work:

```
es:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      person:
        name: Nombre
```

Which is the correct way to define default attributes across models?

Also I'm using Formtastic and Active Admin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is how im doing. Not perfect but will do the job.

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    attribute_commons: &commons
      name: Nome
      description: Descrição
    user:
      <<: *commons
    role:
      <<: *commons
      level: Nível
    product:
      <<: *commons
      size: Tamanho
```

Comment: This approach is useful though if it is applicable to some but not all models.

Comment: Please check out Halil Özgür answer, which is the correct one.

Answer (score 54):

Move the common `attributes` up one level:

```
es:
  attributes:
    name: Nombre
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        birthday: Etc
```

[Example](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/9622c47e636c0010cc23cf528ac4d9421c4cb6e9/rails/rails5/active_record.yml)

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using yaml to store your tranlation, you should look for aliases and anchors in the yaml references :
http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html

but it is not perfect at all. eg :

```
bill-to:  &id001
    street: |
            123 Tornado Alley
            Suite 16
    city:   East Centerville
    state:  KS

ship-to:  *id001
```